# Responsive Masonry Grid theme with infinite scrolling

Tags: css, tumblr, masonry

I've been working on a grid portfolio Tumblr theme with Masonry, Infinite Scrolling and Images Loaded. I've finally gotten everything looking right and positioned where I want it, but now I'm having trouble getting the posts/photos to resize according to the browser window. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.  I can post my whole Tumblr theme code if that would help. 
Here is a link to the theme I'm working on: http://theme12014my.tumblr.com/

Grid layout CSS

```
.article
 {margin:1px;
float:left;
   text-align:center; 
   width:300px; 
   break-inside: avoid; display:inline-block; max-width:50% auto;
}
.content {
max-width:970px;
background-color:#000;
 margin: auto; 
   }
```

Masonry Infinite Scroll Images Loaded script

```
<script>(function() {
var $tumblelog = $('.content');

$tumblelog.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : ".pagination",            
    nextSelector : ".pagination a:first",    
    itemSelector : ".article",
    bufferPx     : 50,
    done : "",
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: "<p> </p>",
        img : " ",
        msg: null,
        msgText: "<p> </p>"
    },
},
  function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            $tumblelog.masonry( 'appended', $newElems);
        });
      }
);




$tumblelog.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $tumblelog.masonry({
    columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
        return containerWidth / 300;
      }
  });    });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `$tumblelog.masonry()` after the window is resized. You can use event `$(window).on("resize", <yourfunction>)` to keep track of that.

Note that the masonry container itself has to be responsible, since mansory will use the container size to calculate how tiles should be placed on screen.

Comment: That sounds about like what I need. I'm not too good with Jquery so I'm not too sure how to go about adding it to the Masonry script. Also, do you know how I could make my masonry container div responsive while keeping it centered to the page?  My container is .content. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css**

```
img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: That did nothing for me, unfortunately. Thank you for suggesting it though.